# Unable to create environments file. Path not writable. Mac M1 Chip python modules

Tags: python-3.x, apple-m1

Hi I'm trying to install TensorFlow for MAC M1 Chip OS 12.0. Post installing the application and trying to install numpy and Jupiter notebook using the below command

```
conda install notebook - y

conda install -c conda-forge numpy -y
```

I get the error

```
Unable to create environments file. Path not writable.
  environment location: /Users/ren/.conda/environments.txt

done
Executing transaction: | WARNING conda.core.envs_manager:register_env(50): Unable to register environment. Path not writable or missing.
  environment location: /Users/ren/miniforge3
  registry file: /Users/ren/.conda/environments.txt
```

I went to the folder and changed the permissions of the file manually it did not work

I ran the command `775 /.conda/` from the terminal it did not work. I removed all the folders for anaconda and Miniforge multiple times I get the same error.

Any suggestions how to get this to work?

Regards,
Ren

Comment: did you run `775 /Users/ren/.conda` or did you run `chmod 775 /Users/ren/.conda`?

Comment: `chmod 775 /Users/ren/.conda` and it did not work.  This worked for me finally after deleting the conda folder and restarting the system multiple times `sudo chmod -R 775 /Users/Ren/.conda`

Answer (score 2):

`sudo chmod -R 775 /Users/Ren/.conda` Worked for me after trying multiple solutions.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by manually `chmod`ing the file path.

```
sudo chmod 775 /Users/michaelmoreno/.conda/environments.txt
```